# Sessions are not getting declared

Tags: php, session, session-variables

This is my login code

```
global $connection;

if (isset($_POST['user_login'])) {

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $password= md5($password);

    $login = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email ='{$email}' AND password = '{$password}' ");
    if(!$login) {
        die("QUERY FAILED" . mysqli_error($connection));
    }

    if(!$login || mysqli_num_rows($login) == 0) {

        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'> <strong>Your Username or Password is invalid!</strong></div>";

    } else {
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

        header('Location: index.php');
    }
}
```

I used the print_r function to display all the sessions but only the session email is getting declared. Why isn't the user_id and username not getting declared? What did I do wrong?

Comment: did you start the session? it doesn't look like it to me

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You should use [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) prepared statements with bound parameters as described in [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: MD5 is not sufficient for password hashing. Use [`password_hash()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead.

Comment: or your POST arrays failed. and `$user_id`

Comment: You don't define `$user_id` or `$username` anywhere. Where do you think they come from?

Comment: Yes, I started the session in the Database page.

Comment: error reporting via php will help you

Comment: Where did you declare `$user_id` and `$username`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You might forget to declare `session_start();` at the top.
2. It seems like you are using `user_id` and `username` in your sessions but they are not fetched from anywhere in your `PHP` code. So, you might forget to get and then use them from your `$login` response.

> This is an assumption because your code looks to use `user_id` and
>   `username` on the basis of `SELECT` query.

So, you can try using this code which has all parameters used from select query:

```
session_start();
global $connection;

if (isset($_POST['user_login'])) {

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $password= md5($password);

    $login = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email ='{$email}' AND password = '{$password}' LIMIT 1");
    if(!$login) {
        die("QUERY FAILED" . mysqli_error($connection));
    }

    if(!$login || mysqli_num_rows($login) == 0) {

        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'> <strong>Your Username or Password is invalid!</strong></div>";

    } else {
        // get user_id and username fetched from your Select query
        while($row = $login->fetch_assoc()) {
          $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id']; // assuming user_id as a column
          $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
          $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username']; // assuming username as a column
        }
        header('Location: index.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: Person who gave down-vote should explain the reason here at least? :)

Comment: Not my downvote, but instead of dumping a bunch of code and saying "try this", adding an explanation as to what was changed, and why, makes the answer so much better - for OP and future readers.

Comment: @Satish Saini - Thank you, got it to work. :) Sorry, they don't allow me to up-vote.

Comment: @Qirel have updated it to make it more clear! Thanks for your comment because that really makes this platform more useful.

Comment: @Unknown: Glad that I was able to trace your mind and gave you expected stuff! Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

When you try to put not initilized variable or null value into session, session don't raise the exception. But key and value list, can not add not init variable or null value.